# How do I deploy into an app that was created by CF?

Tags: git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have a rails app that relies on Redis. I created a CF template that contains `ElasticCache` for Redis and `ElasticBeanstalk` for the rails app.
The whole idea is that a developer (or production) will launch a stack with the template and have his own version that he can play with.

Version management is done with `git` and ideally I'd like to push new versions (and the initial one) to EB using something like `git push aws master` or `git aws.push`, ...

EB commandline tools don't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for, as I don't want the developer to create the application or the environment from his commandline. That should be bundled together with his instance of Redis (and some system variables must be set accordingly).

Can I go the other way around? Having someone creating a stack, and one of its outputs will be something like a git remote repo which he can add locally?
Any simpler ways to handle this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your needs exceed Elastic Beanstalk's offering. EB is not easy to setup and is based on the notion that you work hard to set it up, but enjoy your labor afterwards. In your case, since building the env is the main goal, you'd need to automate redis creation, env creation, env deployment and only then can you give this to the developer. If you want to use EB for that, I recommend creating an env per developer **manually** and let the developer do his `eb deploy`.
If you want the developer to create environments from scratch, I wouldn't pick EB as it seems like the wrong tool (why would a developer need load balancing and auto provisioning?). If i understand correctly, you'd be better with Heroku in this case, or a plain EC2 instance built with Chef.